# How to Use the NearBy Players option in Google Play Game Services in Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games

**Background**

I am developing a Turn based game using Native android development . 
I am able to sign in , send invitations to people who are in G+ circles but i want to send invitation to people who are NearBy .
I am using **Nearby players** option to achieve. 
I saw below links -
https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/6098493
https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/4601849

**Problem**

Both the devices have the game open and NearBy players option turned on.
I have explicitly turned on the bluetooth . Screen displays **Searching for  players nearby**
but both are not able to find each other. 
I have declared this permissions  in AndroidManifest.xml

```
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
```

Is their any other permission which needs to be declared in AndroidManifest.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

It is true that Android platform includes support for the Bluetooth network stack, which allows a device to wirelessly exchange data with other Bluetooth devices as mentioned in [Bluetooth API documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#ManagingAConnection).

However, as far as the documentation shows, a feature of connecting to nearby players using bluetooth hasn't been added yet in Google Play Games services.

As mentioned in [Adding Nearby Connections to Your Game](https://developers.google.com/games/services/cpp/nearby#validating_network_connectivity),

> Before using the Nearby Connections API, you should check to ensure the devices are connected to a WiFi network. If they are not connected, prompt players to connect to a WiFi network.

And, as noted:

> **For devices to discover each other, they must be connected to the same WiFi network with multicast enabled.**

For more information on how to initialize nearby connections and to establish a connection between devices, please check the given [documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/cpp/nearby#top_of_page) and also [Google Play Games Services](https://developers.google.com/games/services/).

Comment: Okay , Thanks @Teyam  !! I checked the above links , the given documentations is in C++ but i am using java , so is their any documentation for java.Any Example/Demo/Sample would be really favorable .

Comment: This [GitHub post](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-nearby/blob/master/connections-quickstart/app/src/main/java/com/google/example/connectionsquickstart/MainActivity.java) might help.